Is there an explicit formula for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this particular symmetric matrix?
Consider a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with the elements $A_{ij}=\min(i,j)$, i.e.:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 2 & \cdots & 2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Is it possible to find explicit formulae for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix?

The eigenvalues are $\left[4\sin^2\left(\frac{j-\frac{1}{2}}{n+\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]^{-1}$ for $j=1,\dots,n$. The asker of the linked question had also derived the eigenvectors.

@user1551 So does that mean that my $A$ is the inverse of the matrix $A_n$ in the linked question? If so, is there an easy way to see that?

Actually no. Your $A$ is $T_n^\top T_n$. Its inverse is $T_n^{-1}(T_n^{-1})^\top$. Let us call this inverse $B_n$. For some reason the asker of the linked question defined $A_n=(T_n^{-1})^\top T_n^{-1}$ instead. But this is not a big deal, as $B_n$ is permutably similar to $A_n$. More specifically $B_n=PAP$ where $P=P^\top=P^{-1}$ is the permutation matrix whose elements on the anti-diagonal are equal to $1$. So, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A_n$ and $u$ is the vector obtained by flipping $v$ up and down, then $u$ is an eigenvector of $B_n$, and in turn also an eigenvector of $A$.
